# Какой выбрать знак для обозначения замедленного действия персонажа?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Я тут как бы рассказ **пишу))**

Мой персонаж **попал в ситуацию**, когда в сервисной службе его стали «затирать», предъявлять нелепые требования. Он хотел уйти, но потом раздумал. Ему захотелось поставить их на место. А дальше как  кино **с замедленным действием:**

**Он **повернулся** к администратору(?)  он тонко **улыбнулся**(?) он **сказал**:* <...>.*

Какие знаки лучше поставить, чтобы обозначить намеренную медленность действия?

Answer (score 1):

«Зна́ки препина́ния — https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  -  элементы письменности, выполняющие вспомогательные функции, например: разделение и выделение смысловых отрезков текста, предложений, словосочетаний, слов, частей слова, указание на грамматические и логические отношения между словами, на коммуникативный тип предложения, его эмоциональную окраску, законченность.
Благодаря знакам препинания, синтаксически оформляющим текст, становится легче воспринимать и понимать текст, а при прочтении вслух — интонационно его оформить (в частности, подчеркнуть смысловые паузы, логические ударения)».

Из этих определений никак не следует, что с помощью знаков препинания можно придать динамики описываемому процессу или замедлить его.
Для «замедления действия» принято использовать иные средства:

- Дигрессия - частичный отход, отклонение в сторону от главной темы...
- Ретрадация – композиционный прием – замедление развития сюжетного действия путем включения в текст повествования внесюжетных элементов...

Как и для чего реализуется концепт "замедления" в литературе:
http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3840304-koncept-zamedlenija-v-literature-kak-realizuetsja-i-dlja-chego.html

Думаю, что ограничиваясь только глаголами совершенного вида (повернулся, улыбнулся, сказал) передать ощущение «замедленности действия» будет совсем непросто.
С опорой на процитированное можно предложить такой вариант:
«Поворачиваясь в сторону администратора он успел согнать с лица следы неудовольствия (/ обиды / озабоченности), после чего, уже (едва заметно) улыбаясь, ровным голосом заговорил: ...».

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Интересно.

Answer (score 0):

В действительности это **[про книгу](https://bestknigi.com/fantastika-i-fjentezi/nauchnaja-fantastika/60215-robert-shekli-iz-lukovicy-v-morkov.html)**

Мне понравилась **там смелость решения**: автор просто поставил **точки.**

***Он повернулся к клерку. Он тонко улыбнулся. Он сказал:**<...>.*

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Говард Кордл** — милый, приятный человек, которого все всегда **оттирали и задевали.** Он молча переживал, когда другие становились впереди него в очередь, садились в остановленное им такси и уводили знакомых девушек...

*— Да мне бы просто попечатать я не собираюсь жениться на ней.*

*Клерк пожал плечами.*

*— Послушайте, мой паспорт в гостинице у портье. Может, возьмете водительские права?*

*— Конечно, нет! У меня должен быть паспорт — на случай, если вы вздумаете скрыться.*

*— Но почему и паспорт, и залог? — недоумевал Кордл, чувствуя определенную неловкость. — Машинка-то не стоит и двадцати долларов.*

*— Вы, очевидно, эксперт, специалист по рыночным ценам в Испании на подержанные немецкие пишущие машинки?*

*— Нет, однако…*

*— Тогда позвольте, сэр, вести дело, как я считаю нужным. Кроме того, мне необходимо знать, как вы собираетесь использовать аппарат.*

*Сложилась одна из тех нелепых ситуаций, в которую может попасть каждый. Требования клерка были **абсурдны**, а манера держаться **оскорбительна.** Кордл уже решил коротко кивнуть, повернуться на каблуках и выйти, но ... внезапно в голову пришла мысль, что он может быть *любым овощем*, каким только пожелает.*

***Он повернулся к клерку. Он тонко улыбнулся. Он сказал:***

*— Хотите знать, как я собираюсь использовать машинку? Признаюсь честно, я собрался засунуть ее в нос.*

*Клерк выпучил глаза.*

*— Это чрезвычайно удачный метод провоза контрабанды, — продолжал Кордл. Также я собирался всучить вам краденый паспорт и фальшивые деньги. В Италии я продал бы машинку за десять тысяч долларов.*